# PIC Micro and unable to locate 'inttypes.h'

Tags: c, header, pic

I have a C language code and I'm going to run on a PIC microcontroller.I am using a Mplab IDE 8.92 with Mplab C18 3.46.I've never done this before with microcontroller. 
Before I have compiled this code using Mingw.But now that the Mplab I use it I get an error:
unable to locate 'inttypes.h'
How do I solve this problem and same problems?

Edit---------
my micro is PIC18f2550.I have used the mplab c18 and mplab xc8 and Both were error.then for test I have used the mplab xc32 and micro piC32...!Was compiled without any problems.
can i use x32 header file for xc8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inttypes.h` is a C99 file and MPLAB C18 only supports C89.

> How do I solve this problem and same problems?

`inttypes.h` defines some macros and includes `stdint.h` C99 header. Try to remove the include line of `inttypes.h` in your source file and declares yourself the missing types (like `typedef unsigned char uint8_t;`, etc.).

Comment: Can you give an example

Comment: Well the example is `typedef unsigned char uint8_t;`.

Comment: Mplab xc8  has the same problem?

Comment: @user3161225 I don't know MPLAX XC8, but by having a quick look at its documentation, C99 is not supported but some selected features of C99 are supported and `stdint.h` is present (`inttypes.h` may be not present but including `stdint.h` may be enough for have your source files to compile).

Comment: my micro is PIC18f2550.I have used the mplab c18 and mplab xc8 and Both were error.then for test I have used the mplab xc32 and micro piC32...!Was compiled without any problems.
can i use x32 header file for xc8?

Comment: @user3161225 no, you'll get bigger problems. Do what I said, remove the `inttypes.h` include directive and fix the compilation errors by defining the missing stuff.